# How do I make a new line after every symbol in a string?

Tags: php

I have a string that goes something like this:

```
This is line 1.* This is line 2.* This is line 3.
```

And it should be formatted like this:

```
This is line 1.
This is line 2.
This is line 3.
```

I was thinking that this has to be done using `substr()` or something of the likes, but I have no clue.

Comment: @Dagon Yes, but do I just replace the `*` with that using `substr()`?

Comment: A simple `str_replace` will do.

Comment: how about str_replace ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and [nl2br](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function.

```
<?php 
    $str = "This is line 1.* This is line 2.* This is line 3.";
    echo nl2br(str_replace("*", "\n", $str));    
?>
```

Comment: i don't see where he says he wants  `<br>` ?

Comment: @Dagon Actually, I should have specified that I want it to be on a newline when I echo into HTML.

Comment: well score 1 for guessing randomly.

Answer (score 3):

This will do it for you :)

```
$s = "This is line 1.* This is line 2.* This is line 3.";

$d = implode("\n", explode('* ', $s));
```

Which returns this:

```
This is line 1.
This is line 2.
This is line 3.
```

[**Example**](https://eval.in/177162)

---

Alternatively you could do something like this using `str_replace()`:

```
$s = "This is line 1.* This is line 2.* This is line 3.";

$s = str_replace("* ", "\n", $s);
```

[**Example**](https://eval.in/177166)

Answer (score -1):

Use explode() function to split this string.

Comment: will create an array, but thats not what he asked for.